# VirtualBox refuses to start VM: `The device helper structure version has changed`

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox suddenly started to refuse launching existing VMs, with this appearing in the log:

```
00:00:03.946244 HDA: Reset
00:00:03.946359 AssertLogRel /mnt/tinderbox/extpacks-5.0/src/VBox/Devices/USB/DevEHCI.cpp(4955) int ehciR3Construct(PDMDEVINS*, int, CFGMNODE*): PDM_VERSION_ARE_COMPATIBLE((pDevIns)->pHlpR3->u32Version, PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION)
00:00:03.946378 DevHlp=0xffe700f1  mine=0xffe700e1
00:00:03.946407 PDM: Failed to construct 'usb-ehci'/0! VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH (-2871) - The device helper structure version has changed.
00:00:03.946421 If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox.
00:00:04.037170 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
00:00:04.037303 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
00:00:04.037317 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf, used:0)
00:00:04.037328 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
00:00:04.037422 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
00:00:04.037488 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
00:00:04.037530 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
00:00:04.039388 VMSetError: /build/virtualbox-JETMa8/virtualbox-5.0.14-dfsg/src/VBox/VMM/VMMR3/VM.cpp(365) int VMR3Create(uint32_t, PCVMM2USERMETHODS, PFNVMATERROR, void*, PFNCFGMCONSTRUCTOR, void*, VM**, UVM**); rc=VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH
00:00:04.039394 VMSetError: The device helper structure version has changed.
00:00:04.039394 If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox.
00:00:04.039582 ERROR [COM]: aRC=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={The device helper structure version has changed.
00:00:04.039587 If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:04.116659 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:04.338867 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
00:00:04.349471 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 2789x1563
00:00:04.349542 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={7303a66d-433b-25a4-f9a8-fcadf87e0c2a} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Strangely, I got this problem when starting one machine but not the others. Upgrading the extension pack still worked, but I forgot to check the old version. Maybe Windows 10 relies on some feature(s) of the newer extension pack but Linux doesn't?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is typical behavior of VirtualBox after it has been upgraded by Ubuntu while it was running.

Solution:

- Stop VirtualBox
- Download the latest extension pack at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads (it is the same for all platforms)
- Install the extension
- Restart Ubuntu

It should now work with any VM that worked previously.

Actually, the log contains this very tip: `If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs`.

Comment: You might not need to restart Ubuntu. After extension install, fire your vm and be going.

Comment: If you need to get this running and you don't have internet you can remove the extension pack from `FIle->Preferences->Extensions` and set USB controller to 1.0, that should allow you to boot (without extensions).

Comment: @rrosa: Interesting! Could you please post that as a new answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

If you need to get this running and you don't have internet you can remove the extension pack:

```
FIle->Preferences->Extensions
```

And set USB controller to 1.1 in machine you want to boot. Select it, then:

```
Machine->Settings->USB->Set it to 1.1 (or disable it)
```

That should allow you to boot. You will not have extensions available, but is may get you through until you get internet. When you get online follow [Nicolas Raoul' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731573/83198)

Comment: Allowed me to boot after copying a VM from Ubuntu to a Windows host. Both hosts had the most current Extension pack installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04:

- Uninstall VirtualBox `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox`
- Uninstall VirtualBox DKMS `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms`
- Download latest version of Virtualbox at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
  (AMD64 for Ubuntu 16.04, if you're on 64bit. Otherwise, choose i386)
- Install the downloaded package `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_...`

You can now run VirtualBox (find in launcher or run `virtualbox`) and all virtual machines will be working again!